# php rid variable after go to 2nd page in pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I'm using php pagination in my webpage but after go to 2nd page with help of pagination php rid the variable which I REQUEST from the last page, and getting the error like,

```
Undefined index: title_no in E:\........\page_name.php on line 7
```

but when I'm using static variable then its working fine, but in dynamic it's rid the variable after go to 2nd page, This is some code of pagination where I'm getting problem

```
ob_start();
@session_start();
include("connect.php");
$title_no=@$_REQUEST['title_no'];
$tbl_name="postadd";

$adjacents = 2;
$productQuery = " where visible='1' AND title_no='{$_REQUEST['title_no']}'";

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name $productQuery";
$total_pages_row = mysql_query($query);
$total_pages_num = mysql_fetch_assoc($total_pages_row);
$total_pages = $total_pages_num['num'];

$targetpage = "product_listing_working.php";    
$limit_val = @$_GET['pagesize'];
if($limit_val!='') {
    $limit = $limit_val;
} else {
    $limit = 3;     
}
$page = @$_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
else
    $start = 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name $productQuery LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Please guide me where I'm going wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$title_no=@$_GET['title_no'];
```

EDIT 1

Try this also

```
$title_no=@$_GET['title_no'];
var_dump($_GET);//get all variables sent to GET
$tbl_name="postadd";

$adjacents = 2;
$productQuery = " where visible='1' AND title_no='.$title_no.'";//changed concataination to a cleaner way
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Chopchop, after using @$_GET['title_no'] error is not showing its good but not displaying any output so what should again, but still use static value getting exact output which I want. :(

Comment: i changed my answer to include some other tests

Comment: $Chopchop after use new code, I'm not getting any output from $productQuery only showing var_dum($_GET) output.